# Can I change the group portion of the git path name in GitLab?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using [GitLab](http://gitlab.org) v6.2.4.

I have a group named *Face Recognition* and a project *facedetect* under it, whose git path name is `git@mygitlab:face-recognition/facedetect.git`. For some reason, I want to change the git path name to be `git@mygitlab:facerecognition/facedetect.git`, that is to say, remove the minus punctuation `-` from the name.

I had try and search but failed to know how to do it. Any one can tell me if there is a method to do it?

---

Update 1/4/2014:
I tried like this

[image]

and I got a 404 error *The page you were looking for doesn't exist*.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a GitLab with me right now to test. On the settings page of a project, at the bottom you can toggle the "dnagerous options section", where you can edit the url of the project. If the group part of the url is not editable, then I think you cannot do it. If you want to name all repositories in the group like this then maybe you want to rename the group itself to not have a space in the name, so that the urls won't have a dash either.

Comment: @janos What I've known are just as you said above.

Comment: @CookSchelling Plus this looks like https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3550: would a brand new GitLab session (in a new browser) show your project correctly renamed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A project's URL in GitLab contains a *namespace* part and a *project* part.  The first part of the name `git@mygitlab:face-recognition/facedetect.git`, *face-recognition*, is the namespace, while *facedetect.git* is the project part.

What you are asking is to rename the *namespace* to which the project belongs.  A namespace is either a *group* or a *user* in GitLab.  You

You can rename a group or change its path from the group's Settings page:
[image: GitLab rename group]

Comment: After a rename, will the old URL be automatically redirected to the new one, or will the links that reference the old namespace be broken?

Comment: @TimRae currently the old URL will be broken.  But there is a feature request https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17361 to add this obvious and desirable feature.  Go comment and vote on the issue there if you want.  GitLab have been quite responsive to user input in the past.

Answer (score 0):

That was asked in [issue 2427](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2427), and supposedly fixed in [commit 233eb1c](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/233eb1c693178068cb769e1633df81e938c543ee) ([GitLab 5.3+](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/a2355c52507a40ed1805e4e6138778bbd0011ee4/CHANGELOG#L20), note that there were a [bug fixed in 6.4.1](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/a2355c52507a40ed1805e4e6138778bbd0011ee4/CHANGELOG#L20))

Renaming a repo (edit project) should allow you to change its path (group or namespace) as well.

[image: https://assets.digitalocean.com/articles/gitlab_use/create_project.png]

Comment: I had not catch the point how to change the group portion. I knew how to change the project portion of the path name but I found no way to change group portion. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: @CookSchelling there should be a "rename" tab, which gives you the possibility to modify the path of your project. Note that only GitLab 6.0 will move your wiki as well (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/23f53c4).

Comment: I had tried it. But it's not allowed to including `/` character in the path name. So it seems this *rename* just used to rename the project name instead of the group name.

Comment: @CookSchelling Strange, what is the exact error message you see? I don't see anything in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/233eb1c693178068cb769e1633df81e938c543ee/app/views/projects/edit.html.haml#L142-L158 which would prevent the use of '`/`'.

Comment: @CookSchelling Could you test the same with the latest 6.4.3 GitLab?